# Minimum and maximum eigenvalue of matrix products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume I have an $n\times n$ positive semidefinite matrix (only non-negative eigenvalues) $A$ so the eigenvalues can be ordered
\begin{equation}
0\leq\lambda_{A,1}\leq\lambda_{A,2}...\leq\lambda_{A,n}\;.
\end{equation}
I have another $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix $B$ with $\mu$ negative eigenvalues and $\pi$ positive eigenvalues, which are ordered
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{B,1}\leq\lambda_{B,2}...\leq\lambda_{B,\mu}\leq0\leq\lambda_{B,n-\pi+1}...\leq\lambda_{B_,n}\;.
\end{equation}

Assuming both A and B are non-singular will the product matrix $AB$ still have $\mu$ negative eigenvalues?

This is obviously true when $A$ and $B$ share a commmon eigenbasis but I want to know if it is true more generally. I observe this to be true numerically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the eigenvalues of $A$ are strictly positive, then the answer is yes. In particular, we note that $AB$ is similar to
$$
A^{-1/2}(AB)A^{1/2} = A^{1/2} B A^{1/2},
$$
where $A^{1/2}$ denotes the unique positive semidefinite square root of $A$. By [Sylvester's law of intertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ will have $\mu$ negative eigenvalues and $\pi$ positive eigenvalues, so the same must be true for $AB$.

More generally, we cannot guarantee that this is the case. For example,
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&-1}.
$$
$B$ has one negative eigenvalue, but $AB$ has no negative eigenvalues.

Comment: I suspect that the following holds: if $Ax$ is non-zero for every eigenvector $x$ of $B$ associated with a negative eigenvalue of $B$, then it will be the case that $AB$ and $B$ have the same number of negative eigenvalues.